# Codeigniter join two table by UNION

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

I'm using codeigniter framework here I'm getting the value through datatable now I want to get the data from two table like below.

```
Table 1
id   Name  Age
1    Sam   26
2    Geo   36
5    Sant  12

Table 2
id   Name  Age
3    Jhon  25
2    Geo   45
7    Negir 17

Result
    id   Name  Age
    1    Sam   26
    2    Geo   45
    3    Jhon  25
    5    Sant  12
    7    Negir 17
```

You can see I merged two tables and id 2 has 45 which override the first one. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sql query to get records

```
SELECT id,name,age
FROM table1
GROUP BY id,name
UNION 
SELECT id,name,age
FROM table2
GROUP BY id,name order by id asc
```

We can use this query in codeigniter way:-

```
$this->db->query("SELECT id,name,age FROM table1 GROUP BY id,name UNION  SELECT id,name,age FROM table2 GROUP BY id,name order by id asc");
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such a situation is to get the `compiled_select()` of the individual select queries, then I merge them into a single query with the help of `$this->db->query()`.
Here's what you can do:

```
$this->db->select('id,name,age');
$this->db->from('table1');
$query_1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('id,name,age');
$this->db->from('table2');
$query_2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$final_query = $this->db->query($query_1 . ' UNION ' . $query_2);

$result = $final_query->result_array();
```

You can then get your values from the `$result` variable as usual.